# how to add foreign key to table that reference to column of data type blob

Tags: mysql, database

My problem:
i created two tables using mysql
the first table called team and it has team id and team name
the second table media table and it has  id and image of type blob 
i want to add foreign key in table team refernce to column image in media table 
i searched google but i found that i can not do this way 
so if i can not is there any way to add a foreign key reference to column that hold image data?

this is the team table

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `TE_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `TE_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and this media table

```
CREATE TABLE `media`(
`media_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`media_jpg` BLOB
);ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

i hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule keys should be small and easy to use, reference, etc. Don't use the `BLOB` as a foreign key, but use its ID instead. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE `media`(
  `media_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `media_jpg` BLOB
);ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then, create the table that references this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `team` (
  `TE_ID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `TE_Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   image_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
   constraint fk1 foreign key (image_id) references `media` (`media_id`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also, you don't need to use backticks to enclose every column name. Use them only when you have names with spaces or special characters. It doesn't seem to be the case in any of your table or column names.

Comment: how if i want to display the image in my website from that table?

Comment: @PRO typically you would join to the table the foreign key references. A fk is not like an additional pointer to a single instance of data, it is field where the value must be a copy of the data from the referenced field... used to guarantee referential integrity.